# How do I implement a switch-case of different functions in python?

Tags: python-3.x

How do I implement a switch-case of different functions in python? The function arguments are different in each case.

Comment: Please provide some code or more information on the context of your problem

Comment: @Lennart Regebro: you've used a wrong link (copy-paste error?)

Comment: Yeah. Well, it's a duplicate anyway. And not a real question. :-/

Answer (score 1):

Python does not have a switch-case statement. You could of course use if/elif-blocks instead to test a variable and call the relevant function depending on the variables value. But I think you could implement a more elegant solution using Pythons built-in dictionaries. The arguments are held in a list and/or dictionary and passed directly to the called function.

Something along the line of:

```
def function1(arg1, arg2):
    print "I'm function1"

def function2(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    print "I'm function2"

functions = {"key1": function1,
             "key2": function2}

switch_var = "key2"
args = [1, 2, 3]
kwargs = {}

functions[switch_var](*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
if case1:
   function1()
elif case2:
   function2(arg1, arg2)
elif case3:
   function3(arg3)
```

etc.